# Calculating distance between previous and current addresses for large file in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, distance, distance-matrix

I'm a fairly new QGIS user.

I have a large dataset (5000+ records) of customer addresses, previous and current, and I want to calculate the distance moved for each customer. Ideally this would be via roads, not as the crow flies, but this is national-level data and I don't yet have any shapefiles for roads covering the whole country (US). I don't have the file yet, but I believe it will have lat/long.

1. is there any way to do this without locating/downloading a national street file?
2. How would I go about solving the problem either way?

Answer (score 1):

If all you have is an address, then the first thing you will have to do is geocode those addresses so they actually have coordinates. If you do have the lat/lon, you'll have to create points out of those coordinates (unless you just want to use spreadsheet calculations).

Without a road network, you can only get the Euclidean (as the crow flies) distance. Since you're looking for distances between specific points and not all of them, the simplest solution is select the two points for the same customer (you'll have to figure out how to determine that - if a name works or if there are customer id numbers), and then draw a line between those two points. The line length is your distance (there are other questions here with this solution).  Alternatively, you could use the distance matrix tool and get the distances between *all* points, then filter that list down using a query where the two name/id fields match.

If you want distance via road network, you'll have to have a road network. You'll also then have to work with routing to solve the distances. ArcGIS has a tool in its Network Analyst extension called OD Cost Matrix, which does the same thing as the distance matrix tool in QGIS but along the network. However to my knowledge (and this is also another question on here), no such corresponding tool exists in QGIS.

Comment: Thanks much for the response.  A follow up:  So, if I only want the euclidean distance, I still have to do it manually for each customer?  There is now way to do it as a batch, like a calculate field query?

Comment: @JesseZaro-Moore Not necessarily - the Distance Matrix does it all at once, you just have to filter down the result. I'm not sure on the details of the line between two points method (I thought it was all at once, but maybe it was manually). I know it was part of an answer I've seen in the last couple of weeks, but I can't find it right now. 5k records isn't that large, so it wouldn't be a big processing hit to just distance matrix them all. Have all customers moved? If not maybe you want to filter that down a bit to just the ones that have.

Comment: Thanks, Chris--By default all of our customers have moved--we are a large national homebuilder and I'm trying to develop a report that shows us how far our customers are moving in each of our divisions when they purchase a home (i.e., are they relocating from around the corner, across town, or from out of town, etc).

Comment: @JesseZaro-Moore If you have 5k customer records and each record has two addresses, that's actually 10k records/points. You may have to do some additional pre-processing to get things into a useable format for the distance matrix tool. You might also then just consider going the spreadsheet calculation route. There's a few questions on that method here, several in that Related column on the right.